# Can Doctrine_RawSql be used with sfDoctrinePager?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a complex query that needs to be performed on given relationships (INNER JOINS) that are not defined in the Symfony schema.  The query itself already takes quite some time, so I've opted to exclude it from the Doctrine schema and elected to use raw queries isntead.  However, I would still like to to use the Doctrine pagination within the Symfony framework.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is.

After you create the query with Doctrine_RawSql you just have to add it to the pager. For example:

```
$query = new Doctrine_RawSql();
$query->addComponent('a', 'Class')->where('a.id = ?', 1);
$pager = new sfDoctrinePager('Class', 25);
$pager->setQuery($query);
$pager->init();
```